# Accepted answer deleted by moderator

Tags: discussion

One of my answers :

[Where can I check the value of $Setup variables?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/6043/where-can-i-check-the-value-of-setup-variables/6045#6045)

Was deleted by a moderator today, even though it was accepted by the asker some time ago. I can't see why it was deleted. Should mods have to leave a comment in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bob - I deleted the Q because OP requested that. While trying to respect both OP's and Answerers, I guess some conflict points may arise.

By mistake I have deleted your answer, and not the question itself - that was fixed

That's a slight: oopsie  :-)

BTW:  After some further reading, looking into the OP's questions - I decided to Undelete them.

Comment: Interesting. Do posters have to justify deleting questions? It seems a bit off to ask for and receive help through a site like this but then not want to leave it for others to learn from. Not so much for this specific case, more from a general perspective.

Comment: You are correct, and there is the question that this was homework question, and caught (or not). BTW: After further reading, and with other mods disucssion - OP's questions were returned. And yes, some reasons for delete ARE viable.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Salesforce is my first foray into stack exchange so these edge cases are still new to me. I agree there are good reasons - e.g. sensitive data. I was more curious as to the protocol.

Comment: One thing I've found with the mod tools so far is they seem to be a bit all or nothing in certain scenarios which can make things tricky; but the overall aim is to generate the most accurate and useful resource possible.